# Python env in R: Installing python packages in R

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I want to read a python file in R and I am using reticulate package for that.

I have certain packages in python file. Do I have to install them in R env again somehow, for the file to run? And how do I do that?
I am getting this error:

```
  Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'descartes'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Just install them directly in python, and it should work

Comment: @Oliver It didn't work. I had to use `py_install("package_name")` for all packages. Any way I could create a requirements file and install all packages in R IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was *first installing* the python customLibrary [via the python command line interface](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).

Second, in my R project folder I specified the python function in a file *customLibrary.py which specifies import as first line*, such as:

```
import customLibrary as CL
def custoFunction(path):
   A = CL.test(path)
   return(A)
```

Third, I call the function from R via standard `reticulate::source_python("customLibrary.py")` implementation (You may need to check whether your directory-path is correct via R command `getwd()`.)

It may be helpful to start with small steps to narrow down the issue:

- just write a simple function, such as "addThree" that is essentially `y = x + 3` etc.
- try to execute it in python
- try to execute if from R

If both works you can try to do the same thing with the custom library.